# Binary space partition tree for 3D map

Tags: graphics, 3d, tree, rendering

I have a project which takes a picture of topographic map and makes it a 3D object.
When I draw the 3D rectangles of the object, it works very slowly. I read about BSP trees and I didn't really understand it. Can someone please explain how to use BSP in 3D (maybe give an example)? and how to use it in my case, when some mountains in the map cover other parts so I need to organize the rectangles in order to draw them well?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your 3D object is: is it a map with elevation? what's its typical size? And why you think BSP trees are the solution to your slow rendering problem?

Comment: My 3D object contains a list of 3D squares(four 3D points) and I think BSP trees are the solution because there are like 62000 squares and it works really slow. Besides that, I want to know how to use BSP in general.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a simple regular grid where each point has an elevation? And you render this as a list of quads?

Comment: Indeed, and when I draw them as a surface and not as a grid it becomes slow and not organized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In n-D a BSP tree is a spatial partitioning data structure that recursively splits the space into cells using splitting n-D hyperplanes (or even n-D hypersurfaces).

In 2D, the whole space is recursively split with 2D lines (into (possibly infinite) convex polygons).

In 3D, the whole space is recursively split with 3D planes (into (possibly infinite) convex polytopes).

1. **How to build a BSP tree in 3D** (from a model)

   The model is made of a list of primitives (triangles or quads which is I believe what you call rectangles).

   Start with an initial root node in the BSP tree that represents a cell covering the whole 3D space and initially holding all the primitives of your model.

   1. Compute an optimal splitting plane for the considered primitives.

      The goal of this step is to find a plane that will split the primitives into two groups of primitives of approximately the same size (either the same spatial extents or the same count of primitives).

      A simple splitting strategy could be to chose a direction at random (which will be the normal of your plane) for the splitting. Then sort all the primitives spatially along this axis. And traverse the sorted list of primitives to find the position that will split the primitives into two groups of roughly equal size (i.e. this simply finds the median position from the primitives along this axis). With this direction and this position, the splitting plane is defined.

      One typically used splitting strategy is however:

      - Compute the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia_tensor_of_triangle) of all the considered primitives.
      - Compute the [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia_tensor_of_triangle) of all the considered primitives.

      The centroid gives the position of the splitting plane.

      The eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix gives the normal of the splitting plane, which is the direction where the primitives are the most spread (and where the current cell should be split).
   2. Split the current node, create two child nodes and assign primitives to each of them or to the current node.

      Having found a suitable splitting plane in 1., the 3D space can be now be divided into two half-spaces: one positive, pointed to by the plane normal, and one negative (on the other side of the splitting plane). The goal of this step is to cut in half the considered primitives by assigning the primitives to the half-space where they belong.

      Test each primitive of the current node against the splitting plane and assign it to either the left or right child node depending on whether it in the positive half-space or in the negative half-space.

      Some primitives may intersect the splitting plane. They can be clipped by the plane into smaller primitives (and maybe also triangulated) so that these smaller primitives are fully inside one of the half-spaces and only belong to one of the cells corresponding to the child nodes. Another option is to simply attach the overlapping primitives to the current node.

      Apply recursively this splitting strategy to the created child nodes (and their respective child nodes), until some criterion to stop splitting is met (typically not having enough primitives in the current node).
2. **How to use a BSP tree in 3D**

   In all use cases, the hierarchical structure of the BSP tree is used to discard irrelevant part of the model for the query.

   1. Locating a point

      Traverse the BSP tree with your query point. At each node, go left or right depending on where the query point is located w.r.t. to the splitting plane of the node.
   2. Compute a ray / model intersection

      To find all the triangles of your model intersecting a ray (you may need this for picking your map), do something similar to 1.. Traverse the BSP tree with your query ray. At each node, compute the intersection of the ray with the splitting plane. Also check the primitives stored at the node (if any) and report the ones that intersect the ray. Continue traversing the children of this node that whose cell intersect your ray.
   3. Discarding invisible data

      Another possible use is to discard pieces of your model that lie outside the view frustum of your camera (that's probably what you are interested in here). The view frustum is exactly bounded by six planes and has 6 quad faces. Like in 1. and 2., you can traverse the BSP tree, check recursively which cell overlaps with the view frustum and completely discard the ones (and the corresponding pieces of your model) that don't. For the plane / view frustum intersection test, you could check whether any of the 6 quads of the view frustum intersect the plane, or you could conservatively approximate the view frustum with a bounding volume (sphere / axis-aligned bounding box / oriented bounding box) or even do a combination of both.

That being said, the solution to your slow rendering problem might be elsewhere (you may not be able to discard a lot of data with a 3D BSP tree for your model):

1. 62K squares is not that big: if you're using OpenGL, you should however not draw these squares individually or continously stream the geometry to the GPU. You can put all the vertices in a single static vertex buffer and draw the quads by preparing a static index buffer containing the list of indices for the squares with either triangles or (better) triangle strips primitives to draw the corresponding squares in a single draw call.
2. Your data is *highly* structured (a regular grid with elevation). If you happen to have *much* larger data sets (that don't even fit in memory anymore), then you need not only spatial partitioning (that exploits the 2.5D structure of your data and its regularity, like a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)) but perhaps LOD techniques as well (to replace pieces of your data by a cheaper representation instead of simply discarding the data). You should then investigate LOD techniques for terrain rendering. [This page](http://vterrain.org/LOD) lists a few resources (papers + implementations). A simplified Chunked LOD could be used as a starting point.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand how and by what criteria to split the rectangles.

Comment: The criterion to split the primitives is always the location of the primitive with respect to the splitting plane. The splitting plane defines two half-spaces in 3D: one positive (in the direction of the plane normal) and one negative. If the primitive is fully in the positive half-space, then it goes to the left child node. If it is fully in the negative half-space, then it goes to the right child node.

Comment: Then to choose the splitting plane, you have some liberty, the goal is to end up with two sets of primitives of roughly equal size.

Comment: And how to I draw it? Do I take only the left child?

Comment: You draw only what's visible. That's what is described in the 2.3 part, where you discard nodes / cells that are outside the view frustum of your camera. For this, you need to traverse the BSP tree and do view frustum / plane intersect tests to determine which sub-nodes should still be traversed and rendered.

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for! Unfortunately, there are some dead links - it seems like Wikipedia took down the "Inertia tensor of triangle" page, I've found another link that seems to be a copy of the original Wikipedia page: [https://en.formulasearchengine.com/wiki/Inertia_tensor_of_triangle](https://en.formulasearchengine.com/wiki/Inertia_tensor_of_triangle). Check the references as it might just be worth downloading the paper directly.