# mesh partitioning and fast lookup

Tags: c++, data-structures, raytracing

I am writing a raytracer and I am trying to partition some mesh data (points and faces) so i can calculate intersections.

Currently I for every intersection calculation i have to look up every face and see if the ray intersect with it. I am trying to find a faster way to do that, namely only lookup relevant faces.

What is a good data structure for storing the graph data (kd tree? equally partitioned space?)
How can i look up relevant spaces/faces given a ray?

PS: Im using C++

Comment: [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview), [SCOTCH](http://www.labri.fr/perso/pelegrin/scotch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spatial partitioning data structure (a BSP tree, a k-D tree or an octree), or even more generally a bounding volume hierarchy (AABB tree) should do the job. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220521/3146587) to a related question for the construction of a BSP tree from a mesh and its traversal. The C++ library [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html) provides an AABB tree data structure with the required construction and query.